# "Failed to load owners" error in Xcode using GitHub

Tags: xcode, github

I am just starting out trying to connect Xcode to Github. I keep getting this peculiar error, saying "Failed to load owners" whenever I try to create a remote repository from within Xcode under the Source Control Manager. [See the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PedoU.png)

If I ignore the warning, [the upload then fails with this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbSF.png).

I cannot seem to find anything online regarding this, and I cannot for the world notice anything being wrong with my GitHub account. The account itself is also accepted by Xcode (successfully added under the Accounts pane in Preferences).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having had a chat with a kind representative from GitHub Developer Support, it seems like it in my case had to do with my old username and password credentials that was saved on my machine. I quote:

> Sometimes applications can use these old credentials, even if you
>   replace it with the personal access token.
>
> Credentials for git authentication are stored in the Keychain App, and
>   git passes these onto GitHub when pushing changes to a Repository.
>
> I'd suggest checking in the Keychain App for any records with the name
>   `GitHub`.
>
> If they exist, delete those and try the push again.
>
> Git should ask you to enter your username and password and once you
>   re-enter them, the correct credentials should be stored in your
>   Keychain app for future use.

So there you have it. This in fact solved my problem. It could also have had something to do with the personal access token that might not be set up with the proper permissions. If you have the same problem as I had you could also check out the scopes on your personal access token to verify it has access to everything you need. Step 7 on the help guide below has a screenshot of what that looks like:

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 5):

In your GitHub account, when you are creating a personal access token to connect your Xcode to GitHub, you have to check off repo, write:packages, and read:packages.

Shown by the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUiiC.png

Then, you should be able to create the repo without any problems! Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help Katie. Although that wasn't the solution to the problem I had, I am pretty sure that I also would have had to double-check for that as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my GitHub-Profile in the XCode Preferences and setted up again. After that it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's looking for another way. What happened to me is that my personal access token expired, and I needed to generate a new one in Github / setting/ developer/ access token. After I generated a new one, I logged out of Github via Xcode, Logged back in and put in my new access code and cleared the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved through Xcode settings - You need to go to the toolbar -> Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts -> there was an active button to update the GitHub account data. I re-entered my token and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to resolve this issue by doing the following steps provided you already have an active token created:

I went to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > GitHub and updated my token I had recently created in GitHub.